# Netty SSL handler fails incorrectly on badssl.com

Tags: java, android, ssl, ssl-certificate, netty

I'm developing an application that uses Netty to manage its SSL/TLS connections. I'm trying to test that it handles various certificate errors correctly, for which I use badssl.com.

However, when I attempt to connect to badssl.com, an exception is thrown (full callstack traces edited and removed for brevity & clarity):

```
 An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
    io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:442)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:372)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:358)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:350)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)

...
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLEngineImpl.unwrap(OpenSSLEngineImpl.java:436)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:1006)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1094)

...

    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:318)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:219)
...
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:318) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:219) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:113)
```

The following [guide for Android developers links](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonProblems) `Trust anchor for certification path not found.` exceptions with unidentified CAs, self signed certificates, or missing intermediate CAs. But this is not the case with badssl.com - the phone's browser recognizes the certificates, and I can even use HTTPSUrlConnection successfully to contact it.

When I use InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE to initialize my security Netty connects successfully, but this isn't a long term solution.

Here are the relevant code snippets:
Initialize SslContext

```
    sslContext = SslContextBuilder
            .forClient()
            .sslProvider(SslProvider.JDK)
            // TODO p0: Ensure all the versions we support have this algorithm installed
            //.trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
            .build();
```

Add SSL handler:

```
ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
pipeline.addLast(sslContext.newHandler(ch.alloc(), host.getHostName(), host.getPort()));
```

Write HTTP request after authentication:

```
            ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(host).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                @Override
                public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                    String request = "GET https://badssl.com/\n" +
                            "Host: +" + host.getHostName() + "\n" +
                            "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;"
                            + "DNT: 1\n\n";

                    future.channel().writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(
                            request, Charset.forName("ASCII")));
                }
```

What's going on here? Why isn't badssl.com recognized? I also tried a few domains with known bad certificates where the connection seemed to erroneously succeed. The only example given for SSL clients is SecureChatClient, which uses InsecureTrustManager.

I'm using Netty 4.1 and my test phone is an LG G3 with Android 5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your code does not use [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). In this case the TLS handshake to badssl.com will result in the certificate:

```
Subject: ...CN=badssl-fallback-unknown-subdomain-or-no-sni
Issuer:  ...CN=BadSSL Intermediate Certificate Authority
```

This certificate is issued by BadSSL itself and the code correctly complains about *Trust anchor for certification path not found* because this certificate is not signed by a trusted CA.

> .. I can even use HTTPSUrlConnection successfully ..

HTTPSUrlConnection make use of SNI and this the server sends a different certificate which is signed by a trusted CA:

```
Subject: ... CN=*.badssl.com
Issuer:  ... CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
```

Unfortunately documentation of how to use SNI on the client side seems to be rare but it looks like that missing support is a problem [others noticed too](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/3801) and [maybe there is fix](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/1398) in later versions of Netty.

Comment: Hmph, I'm using the latest stable branch. If this still isn't supported that's a major impediment to using Netty.

Comment: Anyway, the root cause your specified is correct, so thank you.